# git - recommended way to work with remote repo and live site

Tags: git, version-control

I'm trying to improve my workflow and hoping for some pointers. This is what I currently do - use a remote git repository (codebasehq), work locally on a couple of machines and push changes to the remote repo. This is currently fine, but I want to also pull from the remote repo to a live or staging site. What's the best practice for doing this? Just checking out a copy to the web root or something more advanced than this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Checking out a copy to web root is fine, but you could also consider a deployment tool such as [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano).  Once you have it set up, you would just issue `cap deploy` from one of your local machines, and it would take care of checking out a fresh copy on the live servers, starting the application, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[Hudson/Jenkins](http://hudson-ci.org/) is a good build automation tool with solid git support. It's another server that you'll need to run. You can configure various jobs on Hudson to deploy to one or many servers, based on time or event triggers.

You can think of it as a convenient way to wire up cron, git commit hooks and bash scripting to execute arbitrary deployment tasks.

As an example workflow, I work on a team with ten other developers. We each work on private branches, and merge into master when our feature is tested and working. When anyone pushes to master, Hudson will pull master, run all the tests and deploy the newest application war to a JBoss server for internal acceptance testing.

Similarly, we have a Hudson job configured to deploy to another JBoss instance every 12 hours. We use this instance for customer demos, so we want it to be slightly less volatile than the truly continuous integration/acceptance testing server.

We also have jobs than run performance tests, that build certain project modules, etc. It's a very flexible platform, with many plugins.